# Nuxt module should be a function: mande/nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxtjs3, pinia

I run my project using `pnpm run dev -o`, it gives me an error telling 
`Nuxt module should be a function: mande/nuxt`

I installed `mande` by using `npm install mande` and added it as a build module as well `buildModules: ['mande/nuxt']` and also include `mande/nuxt` in my `tsconfig.json`. After all these, when I run my project using `pnpm run dev -o`, it gives me an error telling 
`Nuxt module should be a function: mande/nuxt`